# how to filter values in matautocomplete

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

Here is the problem.
I'm trying to filter state names from an object received from an API and I'm getting the values to be displayed in the dropdown. But I'm stuck in filtering the values as shown in this example https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples
Can anybody help me solve this issue?

Here is the html code:

```
 <mat-form-field class="full-width">
                            <mat-label>State</mat-label>
                            <input type="text"
                                   matInput
                                   formControlName="state"
                                   required
                                   [matAutocomplete]="auto">
                              <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete"  >
                              
                                    <mat-option *ngFor="let st of stateListn | async" [value]="st.state" class="mat-option2">
                                        {{st.state}}
                                    </mat-option>
                              
                            </mat-autocomplete>
                          </mat-form-field>
                        <small
                            *ngIf="AddShipperForm.controls['state'].hasError('required') && AddShipperForm.controls['state'].touched"
                            class="form-error-msg"> State Name is required </small>
```

And here is the typescript code:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.userDetails = this.userService.getUserDetails()
    this.createAddShipperForm();
    this.getStatelist();
    this.materialtypelist();
    this.st = this.AddShipperForm.get('state').valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value || '')),
    );
  }
 _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
 getStatelist() {
    this.api.get('customer/getStateList').subscribe(response => {
      this.responsedata = response;
      if (this.responsedata.success == "true") {
        this.stateList = this.responsedata.data;
        
        this.stateListn = this.stateList;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.stateListn.length; i++){
          this.options.push(this.stateListn[i]);
        }
        this.st = of(this. Options);
        

      }
      if (this.responsedata.success == "false") {
        this.confirmServicenew.confirm({ title: this.responsedata.message }).subscribe(res => {

        });
      }

    });
  }
```

Here is the API response:

```
{"data":[{"state":"KARNATAKA"},{"state":"DAMAN AND DIU"},{"state":"DELHI"},{"state":"RAJASTHAN"},{"state":"MANIPUR"},{"state":"WEST BENGAL"},{"state":"ANDHRA PRADESH"},{"state":"MADHYA PRADESH"},{"state":"KERALA"},{"state":"TELANGANA"},{"state":"GUJARAT"},{"state":"BIHAR"},{"state":"CHANDIGARH"},{"state":"GOA"},{"state":"TRIPURA"},{"state":"DADRA AND NAGAR HAVELI"},{"state":"NAGALAND"},{"state":"ASSAM"},{"state":"JHARKHAND"},{"state":"PUNJAB"},{"state":"JAMMU AND KASHMIR"},{"state":"PUDUCHERRY"},{"state":"ANDAMAN AND NICOBAR ISLANDS"},{"state":"MEGHALAYA"},{"state":"MIZORAM"},{"state":"MAHARASHTRA"},{"state":"ARUNACHAL PRADESH"},{"state":"CHHATTISGARH"},{"state":"TAMIL NADU"},{"state":"SIKKIM"},{"state":"LAKSHADWEEP"},{"state":"HARYANA"},{"state":"UTTARAKHAND"},{"state":"UTTAR PRADESH"},{"state":"HIMACHAL PRADESH"},{"state":"ORISSA"},{"state":"RAJASTH"}],"success":"true"}
```

And the error code in client:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'dispose')



 <mat-option *ngFor="let st of stateListn | async" <--- ERROR
```

Comment: This code doesn't call `dispose`, please search or post the stacktrace to see where the error orignated.

Comment: @churill i have posted the error line